# How to connect MySql on NetBeans in Linux OS?

Tags: java, mysql, linux, netbeans

How can I connect or create SQL Database in NetBeans (JAVA language), in Linux?
I tried to make JDBC but it failed and didn't work .

Comment: Please elaborate on what you tried with JDBC and what exactly did not work (the error message, for instance).

Answer (score 0):

use [MySQL Connector](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) to perform `JDBC`

Try to add appropriate `jar`-file to the `CLASSPATH`